# Python 3.10 virtualenv error: "Unable to create process using [PATH of python.exe]"

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv

Mi problem happens after I activate my virtualenv, because when I type commands like "py", "python" or "pip" on the cmd, the error in the title occurs:

Unable to create process using *'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'*

Everything is updated globally, and both pip and python 3.10 are in the system's PATH. I've already tried reinstalling python but nothing changes. Also, when I type python commands outside my virtualenv they work just fine.

Any idea of what could be happening? Sorry if this is a repeated question but I've already tried a lot of different things.